# How to count elements stored within a list

Tags: expl3, latex3

In LaTeX I declared a **`\NewDocumentCommand`** like this:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareListOfValues}{ m m }
{
    \clist_gclear_new:c {g_list_of_values_#1_clist}
    \clist_gset:cn {g_list_of_values_#1_clist} {#2}
}
```

Here's an example on how I'm using it to create nested lists of values:

```
\DeclareListOfValues{MyList}
{
    {14-1-11,73.6,26.4,0,0,0}, 
    {15-1-4,72.7,27.3,0,0,0}, 
    {15-1-6,67.7, 32.3,0,0,0},
    {16-1-10,75.6, 24.4,0,0,0},
    {1562-3-6,68.7,31.3,0,0,0},
    {1562-3-16,71.6,28.4,0,0,0},
    {1563-3-8,85.9,14.1,0,0,0},
    {1563-3-13,71.8,28.2,0,0,0},
    {1564-2-7,58.1,41.9,0,0,0},
    {1564-3-14,56.2,43.8,0,0,0}
}
```

From this values inside the nested lists I automatically create histograms and that works perfectly fine.

**What I need to accomplish now is counting the sublists within the list as well as the elements within the sublists, because this numbers can be different.**

Can anybody help, please?

Br,
Mic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This provides a fully expandable command for counting either the items of the outer list or the items in a sublist thereof.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareListOfValues}{ m m }
  {
    \clist_gclear_new:c {g_list_of_values_#1_clist}
    \clist_gset:cn {g_list_of_values_#1_clist} {#2}
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\CountList}{om}
  {
    \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
      {% no optional argument, count the outer list
       \clist_count:c {g_list_of_values_#2_clist}
      }
      {% optional argument, count the i-th item in the outer list
       \clist_count:e { \clist_item:cn {g_list_of_values_#2_clist} { #1 } }
      }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_count:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareListOfValues{MyList}{
    {14-1-11,73.6,26.4,0,0,0}, 
    {15-1-4,72.7,27.3,0,0,0}, 
    {15-1-6,67.7, 32.3,0,0,0},
    {16-1-10,75.6, 24.4,0,0,0},
    {1562-3-6,68.7,31.3,0,0,0},
    {1562-3-16,71.6,28.4,0,0,0},
    {1563-3-8,85.9,14.1,0,0,0},
    {1563-3-13,71.8,28.2,0,0,0},
    {1564-2-7,58.1,41.9,0,0,0},
    {1564-3-14,56.2,43.8,0,0,0}
}

\begin{document}

\CountList{MyList} (should be 10)

\CountList[1]{MyList} (should be 6)

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's possible, if requested, to add a check whether the optional argument is outside the admissible range.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much))